# RGB to YCbCr conversion in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, bitwise, unit-conversion

I found a Go language code to do RGB to YCbCr conversion from [here](https://golang.org/src/image/color/ycbcr.go)! I ported it to Java:

```
private byte[] generateColorBar(int width,int height) {
    final int  COL[][] =
            {
                    { 255, 255, 255 },  // 100% White
                    { 255, 255,   0 },  // Yellow
                    {   0, 255, 255 },  // Cyan
                    {   0, 255,   0 },  // Green
                    { 255,   0, 255 },  // Magenta
                    { 255,   0,   0 },  // Red
                    {   0,   0, 255 },  // Blue
                    {   0,   0,   0 },  // Black
            };

    int columnHeight = height / COL.length;
    byte[] arr = new byte[width*height*3/2];
    int yOffset = 0;
    int uvOffset = width*height;

    for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            int idx = j / columnHeight;
            int R = COL[idx][0];
            int G = COL[idx][1];
            int B = COL[idx][2];
            int yIndex = j*width+i;
            int uvIndex = j*width/2+i;

            int Y = (19595*R + 38470*G + 7471*B + (1<<15)) >> 16;
            int Cb = -11056*R - 21712*G + 32768*B + (257<<15);
            if ((Cb & 0xff000000) == 0) {
                Cb >>= 16;
            } else {
                Cb = 0xffffffff ^ (Cb >> 31);
            }
            int Cr = 32768*R - 27440*G - 5328*B + (257<<15);
            if ((Cr & 0xff000000) == 0) {
                Cr >>= 16;
            } else {
                Cr = 0xffffffff ^ (Cr >> 31);
            }
            arr[yOffset + yIndex] = (byte) Y;
            if (i%2 == 0 && j%2 == 0) {
                arr[uvOffset + uvIndex] = (byte) Cb;
                arr[uvOffset + uvIndex + 1] = (byte) Cr;
            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Please help review it.

The original Go language code is below:

> ```
> // RGBToYCbCr converts an RGB triple to a Y'CbCr triple.
> func RGBToYCbCr(r, g, b uint8) (uint8, uint8, uint8) {
>   // The JFIF specification says:
>   //  Y' =  0.2990*R + 0.5870*G + 0.1140*B
>   //  Cb = -0.1687*R - 0.3313*G + 0.5000*B + 128
>   //  Cr =  0.5000*R - 0.4187*G - 0.0813*B + 128
>   // https://www.w3.org/Graphics/JPEG/jfif3.pdf says Y but means Y'.
>
>   r1 := int32(r)
>   g1 := int32(g)
>   b1 := int32(b)
>
>   // yy is in range [0,0xff].
>   //
>   // Note that 19595 + 38470 + 7471 equals 65536.
>   yy := (19595*r1 + 38470*g1 + 7471*b1 + 1<<15) >> 16
>
>   // The bit twiddling below is equivalent to
>   //
>   // cb := (-11056*r1 - 21712*g1 + 32768*b1 + 257<<15) >> 16
>   // if cb < 0 {
>   //     cb = 0
>   // } else if cb > 0xff {
>   //     cb = ^int32(0)
>   // }
>   //
>   // but uses fewer branches and is faster.
>   // Note that the uint8 type conversion in the return
>   // statement will convert ^int32(0) to 0xff.
>   // The code below to compute cr uses a similar pattern.
>   //
>   // Note that -11056 - 21712 + 32768 equals 0.
>   cb := -11056*r1 - 21712*g1 + 32768*b1 + 257<<15
>   if uint32(cb)&0xff000000 == 0 {
>       cb >>= 16
>   } else {
>       cb = ^(cb >> 31)
>   }
>
>   // Note that 32768 - 27440 - 5328 equals 0.
>   cr := 32768*r1 - 27440*g1 - 5328*b1 + 257<<15
>   if uint32(cr)&0xff000000 == 0 {
>       cr >>= 16
>   } else {
>       cr = ^(cr >> 31)
>   }
>
>   return uint8(yy), uint8(cb), uint8(cr)
> }
> ```

Comment: Use this formula instead:                int Y = 16 + (((R<<6) + (R<<1) + (G<<7) + G + (B<<4) + (B<<3) + B)>>8);
                int Cb = 128 + ((-((R<<5) + (R<<2) + (R<<1)) - ((G<<6) + (G<<3) + (G<<1)) + (B<<7) - (B<<4))>>8);
                int Cr = 128 + (((R<<7) - (R<<4) - ((G<<6) + (G<<5) - (G<<1)) - ((B<<4) + (B<<1)))>>8);

Comment: I see you removed the statement "_Not sure if it caused by int overflow in java! I try to change it to long but still not helpful!_" and added the statement "_The output sounds good for my color bar, please help review if it's good._". Is the java code working as intended?

Comment: Yes, it works now!

Comment: is there any reason why you use java? one benefit of java is the OOP and i can't see much objects in your code...